# zooming and panning - upgrading d3 code to d3.v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I have been trying to upgrade this code to v4 of d3 with no luck.

```
function xnr(selector) {
var coordinates = [
                        {"id": 1, "x": 120.16353869437225, "y": 160.974180892502466},
            {"id": 2, "x": 190.285414932883366, "y": 259.116836781737214},
            {"id": 3, "x": 310.218762385111142, "y": 170.033297729284202}
            ];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 100]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 100]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 400)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 100]).on("zoom", zoom));

var groups = svg.selectAll("g.leaf")
    .data(coordinates)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "leaf")
    .attr("transform", transform)
    .append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr('stroke', '#aaaaaa')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2px');

function zoom() {
    svg.selectAll("g.leaf").attr("transform", transform);
}

function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
}
}
```

Old code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user1313/64L3s2fq/10/) - works as i need it (semantic zoom).
New code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user1313/tydfz2bj/12/) - only works as geometic zoom.

Mike Bostock's examples for SVG geometric and semantic zooming worked for me in d3 v3, but since the zoom.x() and zoom.y() functions had been removed, i am lost.

Comment: It looks like both versions have semantic zooming working

Comment: hmmm, in my browser, with the second jsfiddle, dots become bigger when you zoom-in

Comment: I'm using chrome and they keep their size. How exactly do you zoom?

Comment: Mouse-scroll up and down. Also using chromium. Does it work as expected here for you?: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999
Do the dots themselves become bigger?

Comment: The link here is for geometric, the dots change their size on zoom.

Comment: True, for geometric. Still, my second jsfiddle works geometric for me. Are you sure you are using the /12 version suffix in the link? I forked it first from the first jsfiddle and then modified, so if you go without /12, you will get the d3.v3 code.

Comment: No, you changed the link. I used this link originally: https://jsfiddle.net/user1313/tydfz2bj/ The /12 link is indeed geometric.

Comment: yes, i updated it as soon as i realized the error, but before your first comment, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Mike Bostock's [Pan & Zoom III](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4e3925cdc804db257a86fdef3a032a45) example can be modified to use semantic zooming as per this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc17kjw0/). The important bits are:

```
var radius = 3;
var circles = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(points)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .attr("r", radius);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
        .on("zoom", zoomed));

function zoomed() {
    var transform = d3.zoomTransform(this);
    circles.attr("transform", transform);
    circles.attr("r", radius/transform.k)
}
```

[zoomTransform](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoomTransform) is a linear transformation of the plane which increases area as it increases distances. If we want the circles to have the same area after zooming, we need to rescale their radii by the scale factor of the transformation, `transform.k`.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example fiddle for semantic zoom for d3 version 4 with click controls, also displaying scale for the reference.

You can use this scale to add any semantic information for the same.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var randomX = d3.randomNormal(width / 2, 80),
  randomY = d3.randomNormal(height / 2, 80),
  data = d3.range(200).map(function() {
    return [randomX(), randomY()];
  });
var scale;

var circle;


var _zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .on("zoom", zoom);

circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("transform", transform(d3.zoomIdentity));

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("pointer-events", "all")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .call(_zoom);

function zoom() {
  circle.attr("transform", transform(d3.event.transform));
  scale = d3.event.transform.k;
  console.log(scale);
  document.getElementById('scale').value = scale;
}

// semantic zoom

function semanticZoom() {
  circle.attr("transform", transform(d3.event.transform));
}

function transform(t) {
  return function(d) {
    return "translate(" + t.apply(d) + ")";
  }
}

var gui = d3.select("#gui");
gui.append("span")
  .classed("zoom-in", true)
  .text("+")
  .on("click", function() {
    _zoom.scaleBy(circle, 1.2);
  });
gui.append("span")
  .classed("zoom-out", true)
  .text("-")
  .on("click", function() {
    _zoom.scaleBy(circle, 0.8);
  });
```

Below is the JS fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/sagarbhanu/5jLbLpac/36/